# How can I control the argument prompts (function hint ) for a handle class method in MatLab?

Tags: matlab

My question is about the prompts that appear when you try to call a method (or a function): I'm referring to the little box that says `(param1 double, param2 char, ...)`. I've been having trouble googling this question, mostly because I'm not sure what this box is called, so please do point me to it if this question is already answered.

If you write a function or a method and use `validateattributes` to specify which input types you're expecting, Matlab will pop up this box, telling you what parameters are called for when you go to call the method.

However, if you write a handle class method then you have to include the object as the first parameter. E.g.:

`function [x] = doSomething(arg, param1, param2, ...)
    fprintf('I did %d things!\n', param1);
end`

But when you try to call this function, the popup box only asks for the `arg` class instance and doesn't mention the other parameters. Like this:

[image: Example image]

**How can I arrange it so that my users get prompted for the correct inputs and not only the class-object itself?**

Comment: "Example image" broken link

Comment: @MicahSmith it displays properly for me

Comment: The box is called [function hint](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/check-syntax-as-you-type.html). The same question [here](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/217145-how-can-i-display-function-hints-for-methods-in-a-class) did not receive an answer. I guess it is not possible currently, submit a feature request.

Comment: Hmmm ok, thanks @m.s.  If you write that up as an answer then I'll accept it, and I'll drop a note to MathWorks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Converting my comment into an answer:*

The box is called [function hint‌](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/check-syntax-as-you-type.html)​. The same question [here](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/217145-how-can-i-display-function-hints-for-methods-in-a-class) did not receive an answer. I guess it is not possible currently, submit a feature request.